# find the range for list of values - 'between' operator in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, range, between

I have list of values in hand. I want to find out the Range in the table in which the value falls.

List of values `(475747003, 476367781, 454313069, 454545398, etc.,)`  — 1000's of values

Ranges in DB table look like:

```
Start_Range      End_Range
--------------------------
475747000        475747999
476367781        476367782
454313059        454313069
```

My output should be like below, i.e I want to find out the `Start_Range` and `End_Range` for all 1000's of values.  I tried using 'Between' operator, however I was not sure how to  use it for the 'list of values'?

```
Start_Range      End_Range
--------------------------
475747000        475747999
476367781        476367782
454313059        454313069
```

So basically, the below sql script throws error,

```
select * from TABLE 
where (475747003, 476367781, 454313069, 454545398) between start_range and end_range;
```

> ORA-01796: this operator cannot be used with lists
>   01796. 00000 -  "this operator cannot be used with lists"

So I want to find alternate way.

Comment: Something with a MAX() and a MIN() or a TOP 1 ORDER BY and TOP 1 ORDER BY DESC where your values are BETWEEN x AND y jumps to mind.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I also don't see a difference between the two examples

Comment: Oracle Version 3.2.10.09

Comment: 1000's of ranges in DB table, I want to find the correct range the value falls in.  But I have a list of values.  Not just one.

Comment: There is no Oracle version 3.2. (The very first version was 6 the latest version is 12.1)

Comment: My software shows that version for me.. Also i added sql script to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: The list of values, how are those stored? row-wise? column-wise?

Comment: To find your Oracle version, run `select * from v$version`. The Oracle version is usually in the first row of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it with a "normal" query (the closest thing is the `IN` operator for a list of values, but you can't test for anything but equality).

What about using a temp table, or even a "virtual" table, like this:

```
select myValues.myValue, r.Start_Range, r.End_Range
from (
    select 11111 as MyValue from dual union all
    select 22222 as MyValue from dual union all
    select 33333 as MyValue from dual union all
    ... // all of the values you want to search for
    select 99999 as MyValue from dual
) as myValues
inner join RangesTable r on myValues.myValue between r.Start_Range and r.End_Range
```

Same thing if you want to use a temp table.  You just have to get the values into something the db can treat as a **set** and then do a join to your ranges.

Comment: Of course this can be done with a "normal" query. `IN` is not the only operator available. `EXISTS` can be used with conditions other than equality (and it would work perfectly fine in this case).

Comment: just saying that you have to turn the "list of values" into a set for set-based operations.  other than that, sure, it's normal.

Comment: Oh, OK - I thought you meant "even if the test values are already in a table, you can only use `IN` and that can't be used with testing for ranges." If what you meant was transforming the list into a table, that's another matter (although the method I illustrated, using `table(sys.odcinumberlist(..))`, is pretty standard too).

Answer (score 0):

In the query below, I mimic the ranges table in a CTE (not part of the solution; in your real-life problem you will simply refer to your table in the main query), and I input the numbers "to be checked against the ranges" as a table of numbers constructed on the fly. You said you only need to show the ranges that match... in the query below I show each individual value and the range it matches (showing NULL if the value doesn't fall within any of the ranges). If you only need actual matches change the `left outer join` to an `inner join`. If you only need the ranges, then don't include `val` in the output (in the `SELECT` clause).

```
with
     ranges_table ( start_range, end_range ) as (
       select 475747000, 475747999 from dual union all
       select 476367781, 476367782 from dual union all 
       select 454313059, 454313069 from dual
     ),
     list_of_values ( val ) as (
       select column_value from table(sys.odcinumberlist
                 (475747003, 476367781, 454313069, 454545398))
     )
select l.val, r.start_range, r.end_range
from   list_of_values l left outer join ranges_table r
                          on l.val between r.start_range and r.end_range
;

VAL        START_RANGE  END_RANGE
---------  -----------  ---------
454313069  454313059    454313069
454545398
475747003  475747000    475747999
476367781  476367781    476367782
```

If you only need the DISTINCT matching ranges (which would make more sense than just dropping the `VAL` column from the above table), you could instead do something like this:

```
select start_range, end_range
from   ranges_table
where  exists ( select val 
                from   list_of_values 
                where  val between start_range and end_range
              )
;
```